# How to specify a TimeZone when creating a DateTime object in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: date, dart, flutter

Dart?flutter does not appear to allow a timezone (eg: "Australia/Sydney" or "America/Detroit") to be specified when creating a DateTime object. Either the local timezone will be used, or UT may be specified.

Is anyone aware of a workaround?

There's the Dart package TimeZone, but it appears to be unusable within a flutter app.

See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/timezone for the package I'm referring to.

EDIT: The timezone package does work in Flutter, with some setup. See Richard Heap's answer below.

Comment: There is no support for that in Dart or Flutter. Why do you think the timezone package can't be used in Flutter?

Comment: The `timezone` plugin will work perfectly fine.

Comment: The TimeZone package does work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to do a bit of magic to get `package:timezone` to work in flutter.

Extract whichever data file you need (there are 3: default, all and 2010-2020) and move it to your flutter assets folder. (I use `2018c_2010-2020.tzf`, which is available in a branch.)

Add it as an asset in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  assets:
    - assets/2018c_2010-2020.tzf
```

Then load that file on startup (e.g. from the `initState` of a top level StatefulWidget) and use it to initialise the database.

```
ByteData tzf = await rootBundle.load('assets/2018c_2010-2020.tzf');
initializeDatabase(tzf.buffer.asUint8List());
...
Location newYork = getLocation('US/Eastern');
```

I haven't tried, but you may even be able to load it from `main` if you mark it async.

I also notice that I must have cloned the latest branch, as I see this in my pubspec

```
  timezone:
    path: ../../dart/source/timezone
```

... but looks like you just need to grab 0.5.0-dev-2 from pub

```
dependencies:
  timezone: "^0.5.0-dev-2"
```

Comment: Where do I get the "2018c_2010-2020.tzf" file?

Comment: From [the github repo](https://github.com/srawlins/timezone/tree/master/lib/data) Note the updated [readme](https://github.com/srawlins/timezone) which has suggestions of how to load the database from `main()`

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

simple add these lines in initState

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   tz.initializeTimeZones();
   final String locationName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
   tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(locationName));
}
```

Comment: flutter_native_timezone is no longer maintained, so it's best to switch to flutter_timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The TimeZone package does work. From the issues list on GitHub:

Sorry this took 6 months but I have a good solution. I think it will be the recommended solution.

See Flutter's docs on Adding Assets. You should be able to add to your Flutter app's pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/timezone/data/2015b.tzf
```

and load in your app with:

```
Future<List<int>> loadDefaultData() async {
  var byteData = await rootBundle.load('packages/timezone/data/2015b.tzf');
  return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}

// Call the above with something like:

loadDefaultData().then((rawData) {
  initializeDatabase(rawData);
  var zurich = getLocation('Europe/Zurich');
});
```

Comment: Would like to note that when including package assets in your app, the `lib` portion of the path needs to be excluded. [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-images-in-package-dependencies) So `packages/timezone/lib/data/2015b.tzf` should be `packages/timezone/data/2015b.tzf`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I'm one of the authors of Sugar.

Dart's `DateTime` doesn't support timezones.

The `timezone` package does work but it requires manually adding the tzf files under the assets sections & initializing the package with `initializeTimeZones()` as mentioned above.

An alternative to the `timezone` package is `sugar`. It doesn't require adding additional files under the assets section in your project's pubspec.yaml or initializing the package.

To use the package, simply create a `ZonedDateTime` (the equivalent of a `TzDateTime`):

```dart
import 'package:sugar/sugar.dart';

void currentTime() {
  final now = ZonedDateTime.now(Timezone('Europe/Zurich'));
}
```

To install the `sugar` package:

```yaml
dependencies:
  sugar: ^3.0.0
```

See the project's [page](https://github.com/forus-labs/cauldron/tree/master/sugar) for more information.