# How to get time according to dynamic time zone current time in flutter

Tags: flutter, time, timezone, datetimeoffset

I have this String **(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam**. Now currently my timezone is India. So when I run

> DateTime.now()

it returns the current India time.

But I want **Amsterdam** time instead of current India time.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/timezone try with this

Comment: @JahidulIslam yes I already see this package but how to find the region according to offset?

Comment: take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780124/how-to-specify-a-timezone-when-creating-a-datetime-object-in-dart-flutter